# Logstash File Input not outputting event after file change

Tags: file, elasticsearch, logstash, logstash-file

I am trying to read from a file and output each events to the console (or a file). I want to be able to add to the file and have this be picked up by Logstash and repeat the pipeline. However, Logstash seems to only read and perform the pipeline once even though it sees that the file has changed.

I am developing on OS X Yosemite.

Here's my LogStash Config

```
input {  
      file {
          path => "/Users/Justin/logstash-1.5.2/testFile"
          sincedb_path => "/Users/Justin/logstash-1.5.2/.sincedb"
          start_position => "beginning"
      }
}


output {  
   stdout {

   }
}
```

Here's the log (also, tried with sudo, no luck):

```
    Justins-MacBook-Pro-2:logstash-1.5.2 justin$ bin/logstash agent --debug -vf myConfig
Reading config file {:file=>"logstash/agent.rb", :level=>:debug, :line=>"295", :method=>"local_config"}
Compiled pipeline code:
        @inputs = []
        @filters = []
        @outputs = []
        @periodic_flushers = []
        @shutdown_flushers = []

          @input_file_1 = plugin("input", "file", LogStash::Util.hash_merge_many({ "path" => ("/Users/Justin/logstash-1.5.2/testFile") }, { "sincedb_path" => ("/Users/Justin/logstash-1.5.2/.sincedb") }, { "start_position" => ("beginning") }))

          @inputs << @input_file_1

          @output_stdout_2 = plugin("output", "stdout")

          @outputs << @output_stdout_2

  def filter_func(event)
    events = [event]
    @logger.debug? && @logger.debug("filter received", :event => event.to_hash)
    events
  end
  def output_func(event)
    @logger.debug? && @logger.debug("output received", :event => event.to_hash)
    @output_stdout_2.handle(event)

  end {:level=>:debug, :file=>"logstash/pipeline.rb", :line=>"28", 
    :method=>"initialize"}
    Plugin not defined in namespace, checking for plugin file {:type=>"input", :name=>"file", :path=>"logstash/inputs/file", :level=>:debug, :file=>"logstash/plugin.rb", :line=>"133", :method=>"lookup"}
    Plugin not defined in namespace, checking for plugin file {:type=>"codec", :name=>"plain", :path=>"logstash/codecs/plain", :level=>:debug, :file=>"logstash/plugin.rb", :line=>"133", :method=>"lookup"}
    config LogStash::Codecs::Plain/@charset = "UTF-8" {:level=>:debug, :file=>"logstash/config/mixin.rb", :line=>"112", :method=>"config_init"}
    config LogStash::Inputs::File/@path = ["/Users/Justin/logstash-1.5.2/testFile"] {:level=>:debug, :file=>"logstash/config/mixin.rb", :line=>"112", :method=>"config_init"}
    config LogStash::Inputs::File/@sincedb_path = "/Users/Justin/logstash-1.5.2/.sincedb" {:level=>:debug, :file=>"logstash/config/mixin.rb", :line=>"112", :method=>"config_init"}
    config LogStash::Inputs::File/@start_position = "beginning" {:level=>:debug, :file=>"logstash/config/mixin.rb", :line=>"112", :method=>"config_init"}
    config LogStash::Inputs::File/@debug = false {:level=>:debug, :file=>"logstash/config/mixin.rb", :line=>"112", :method=>"config_init"}
    config LogStash::Inputs::File/@codec = <LogStash::Codecs::Plain charset=>"UTF-8"> {:level=>:debug, :file=>"logstash/config/mixin.rb", :line=>"112", :method=>"config_init"}
    config LogStash::Inputs::File/@add_field = {} {:level=>:debug, :file=>"logstash/config/mixin.rb", :line=>"112", :method=>"config_init"}
    config LogStash::Inputs::File/@stat_interval = 1 {:level=>:debug, :file=>"logstash/config/mixin.rb", :line=>"112", :method=>"config_init"}
    config LogStash::Inputs::File/@discover_interval = 15 {:level=>:debug, :file=>"logstash/config/mixin.rb", :line=>"112", :method=>"config_init"}
    config LogStash::Inputs::File/@sincedb_write_interval = 15 {:level=>:debug, :file=>"logstash/config/mixin.rb", :line=>"112", :method=>"config_init"}
    config LogStash::Inputs::File/@delimiter = "\n" {:level=>:debug, :file=>"logstash/config/mixin.rb", :line=>"112", :method=>"config_init"}
    Plugin not defined in namespace, checking for plugin file {:type=>"output", :name=>"stdout", :path=>"logstash/outputs/stdout", :level=>:debug, :file=>"logstash/plugin.rb", :line=>"133", :method=>"lookup"}
    Plugin not defined in namespace, checking for plugin file {:type=>"codec", :name=>"line", :path=>"logstash/codecs/line", :level=>:debug, :file=>"logstash/plugin.rb", :line=>"133", :method=>"lookup"}
    config LogStash::Codecs::Line/@charset = "UTF-8" {:level=>:debug, :file=>"logstash/config/mixin.rb", :line=>"112", :method=>"config_init"}
    config LogStash::Outputs::Stdout/@type = "" {:level=>:debug, :file=>"logstash/config/mixin.rb", :line=>"112", :method=>"config_init"}
    config LogStash::Outputs::Stdout/@tags = [] {:level=>:debug, :file=>"logstash/config/mixin.rb", :line=>"112", :method=>"config_init"}
    config LogStash::Outputs::Stdout/@exclude_tags = [] {:level=>:debug, :file=>"logstash/config/mixin.rb", :line=>"112", :method=>"config_init"}
    config LogStash::Outputs::Stdout/@codec = <LogStash::Codecs::Line charset=>"UTF-8"> {:level=>:debug, :file=>"logstash/config/mixin.rb", :line=>"112", :method=>"config_init"}
    config LogStash::Outputs::Stdout/@workers = 1 {:level=>:debug, :file=>"logstash/config/mixin.rb", :line=>"112", :method=>"config_init"}
    Registering file input {:path=>["/Users/Justin/logstash-1.5.2/testFile"], :level=>:info, :file=>"logstash/inputs/file.rb", :line=>"76", :method=>"register"}
    Pipeline started {:level=>:info, :file=>"logstash/pipeline.rb", :line=>"86", :method=>"run"}
    Logstash startup completed
    _sincedb_open: reading from /Users/Justin/logstash-1.5.2/.sincedb {:level=>:debug, :file=>"filewatch/tail.rb", :line=>"220", :method=>"_sincedb_open"}
    _sincedb_open: setting ["11809694", 1, 4] to 1089 {:level=>:debug, :file=>"filewatch/tail.rb", :line=>"224", :method=>"_sincedb_open"}
    _sincedb_open: setting ["11850406", 1, 4] to 15 {:level=>:debug, :file=>"filewatch/tail.rb", :line=>"224", :method=>"_sincedb_open"}
    _discover_file_glob: /Users/Justin/logstash-1.5.2/testFile: glob is: ["/Users/Justin/logstash-1.5.2/testFile"] {:level=>:debug, :file=>"filewatch/watch.rb", :line=>"132", :method=>"_discover_file"}
    _discover_file: /Users/Justin/logstash-1.5.2/testFile: new: /Users/Justin/logstash-1.5.2/testFile (exclude is []) {:level=>:debug, :file=>"filewatch/watch.rb", :line=>"141", :method=>"_discover_file"}
    _open_file: /Users/Justin/logstash-1.5.2/testFile: opening {:level=>:debug, :file=>"filewatch/tail.rb", :line=>"119", :method=>"_open_file"}
    /Users/Justin/logstash-1.5.2/testFile: initial create, no sincedb, seeking to beginning of file {:level=>:debug, :file=>"filewatch/tail.rb", :line=>"156", :method=>"_open_file"}
    Received line {:path=>"/Users/Justin/logstash-1.5.2/testFile", :text=>"Hello World", :level=>:debug, :file=>"logstash/inputs/file.rb", :line=>"137", :method=>"run"}
    Received line {:path=>"/Users/Justin/logstash-1.5.2/testFile", :text=>"Testing", :level=>:debug, :file=>"logstash/inputs/file.rb", :line=>"137", :method=>"run"}
    output received {:event=>{"message"=>"Hello World", "@version"=>"1", "@timestamp"=>"2015-07-21T22:58:13.460Z", "host"=>"Justins-MacBook-Pro-2.local", "path"=>"/Users/Justin/logstash-1.5.2/testFile"}, :level=>:debug, :file=>"(eval)", :line=>"21", :method=>"output_func"}
    writing sincedb (delta since last write = 1437519493) {:level=>:debug, :file=>"filewatch/tail.rb", :line=>"196", :method=>"_read_file"}2015-07-21T22:58:13.460Z Justins-MacBook-Pro-2.local Hello World

    output received {:event=>{"message"=>"Testing", "@version"=>"1", "@timestamp"=>"2015-07-21T22:58:13.464Z", "host"=>"Justins-MacBook-Pro-2.local", "path"=>"/Users/Justin/logstash-1.5.2/testFile"}, :level=>:debug, :file=>"(eval)", :line=>"21", :method=>"output_func"}
    2015-07-21T22:58:13.464Z Justins-MacBook-Pro-2.local Testing
    /Users/Justin/logstash-1.5.2/testFile: file grew, old size 0, new size 20 {:level=>:debug, :file=>"filewatch/watch.rb", :line=>"96", :method=>"each"}
    _discover_file_glob: /Users/Justin/logstash-1.5.2/testFile: glob is: ["/Users/Justin/logstash-1.5.2/testFile"] {:level=>:debug, :file=>"filewatch/watch.rb", :line=>"132", :method=>"_discover_file"}
```

After I change a file (in this case, testFile) this shows up but nothing else:

```
/Users/Justin/logstash-1.5.2/testFile: file grew, old size 20, new size 29 {:level=>:debug, :file=>"filewatch/watch.rb", :line=>"96", :method=>"each"}
_discover_file_glob: /Users/Justin/logstash-1.5.2/testFile: glob is: ["/Users/Justin/logstash-1.5.2/testFile"] {:level=>:debug, :file=>"filewatch/watch.rb", :line=>"132", :method=>"_discover_file"}
```

Also, it doesn't seem to be crashing or anything. It sees that the file has changed but doesn't run its function to output.

Comment: What do you mean by "a change in the file".  Are you editing the file, replacing the entire contents, or appending to it?

Comment: Hey Alain! I am simply appending to it.

Comment: Did you find the solution to your problem ?, if yes, kindly post it.

Answer (score 0):

there is option in logstash config file .

```
 input {
 file {
 discover_interval => ... # number (optional), default: 15
 stat_interval => ... # number (optional), default: 1
 sincedb_path => ... # string (optional)
 sincedb_write_interval => ... # number (optional), default: 15
 }
}
```

here `discover_interval * stat_interval = seconds`
wait for 15 seconds . if still facing same problem delete .sincedb_* files.  and  restart logstash service. sincedb store details all processed files. i hope it will work.

Comment: Still doesn't work :( Just keeps outputting:

_discover_file_glob: /Users/Justin/logstash-1.5.2/testFile: glob is: ["/Users/Justin/logstash-1.5.2/testFile"] {:level=>:debug, :file=>"filewatch/watch.rb", :line=>"132", :method=>"_discover_file"}

Comment: please , uninstall logstash and reinstall fresh logstash or try with other version of logstash . there was some bug in logstash 1.5.0. i don't know that bug is resolved or not. see here also https://discuss.elastic.co/t/logstash-stops-processing-files-after-a-while/944/4